# Animation: objects hidden while moving (JAVA, GRAPHICS, ANIMATION)

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics, event-dispatch-thread

I am build a graph, with a while circle moving along a line, and stoping over for a few seconds at 3 points of the path. 
I have managed to do it, however, it does not display the circle moving, it displays only when the circle stops...
I can't understand why.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Here is my code:

```
public class Robot0 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public Robot0(String nom, int larg, int haut) {
        setTitle(nom); 
        setSize(larg, haut); 
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        setResizable(false); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                     
        setVisible(true); 
    }

    Timer tm = new Timer(10, this);

    private int posX = 0; 
    private int posY = 0;
    private int velX = 1;

    public int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public void setPosX(int posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }

    public int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public void setPosY(int posY) {
        this.posY = posY;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Draw the pathway 
        int xt[] = { 50, 50, 250, 250, 350, 350 };
        int yt[] = { 50, 150, 150, 50, 50, 150 };
        g.drawPolyline(xt, yt, 6);

        // On the pathway, draw 3 squares (the 3 rooms)
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(35, 135, 30, 30);
        g.drawRect(235, 35, 30, 30);
        g.drawRect(335, 135, 30, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(40 + posX, 40 + posY, 20, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(45 + posX, 50 + posY, 55 + posX, 50 + posY);
        g.drawLine(50 + posX, 45 + posY, 50 + posX, 55 + posY);

        tm.start();
    }

    int segment = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // move along the 1st segment
        if (posY < 100 && segment == 0) {
            setPosY(posY + velX);
        }

        if (posY == 100 && posX == 0) {
            segment = 1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Robot0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        // move along the second segment
        if (posX <= 200 && segment == 1) {
            setPosX(posX + velX);
        }

        if (posX == 200 && posY == 100) {
            segment = 2;
        }

        // move along the third segment
        if (posY > 0 && segment == 2) {
            setPosY(posY - velX);
        }

        if (posX == 200 && posY == 0) {
            segment = 3;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Robot0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        // move along the fourth segment
        if (posX < 300 && segment == 3) {
            setPosX(posX + velX);
        }

        if (posX == 300 && posY == 0) {
            segment = 4;
        }

        // move along the fifth segment
        if (posY < 100 && segment == 4) {
            setPosY(posY + velX);
        }

        if (posX == 300 && posY == 100) {
            segment = 6;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Robot0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

// Build the Panel
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot0 r = new Robot0("Robot0", 800, 600);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(15000);` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a single Thread library. All painting tasks are executed in the Event Dispatcher Thread 
([EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)). 
As commented by  Andrew Thompson, running long processes (such as sleep) on the EDT makes keeps this thread busy, so it does not do other things 
like updating the gui. 
The gui becomes unresponsive (freezes).
So the first thing to do is to remove all sleeping.
 To park at each stop, use a second timer:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Robot0 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final int PARKING_TIME = 15000;
    Timer moveTimer , waitTimer;
    private boolean isParking = false;

    public Robot0(String nom, int larg, int haut) {
        moveTimer = new Timer(10, this);
        waitTimer = new Timer(PARKING_TIME, e-> isParking = false);
        waitTimer.setRepeats(false);

        setTitle(nom);
        setSize(larg, haut);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private int posX = 0;
    private int posY = 0;
    private final int velX = 1;

    public int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public void setPosX(int posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }

    public int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public void setPosY(int posY) {
        this.posY = posY;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Draw the pathway
        int xt[] = { 50, 50, 250, 250, 350, 350 };
        int yt[] = { 50, 150, 150, 50, 50, 150 };
        g.drawPolyline(xt, yt, 6);

        // On the pathway, draw 3 squares (the 3 rooms)
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawRect(35, 135, 30, 30);
        g.drawRect(235, 35, 30, 30);
        g.drawRect(335, 135, 30, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(40 + posX, 40 + posY, 20, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(45 + posX, 50 + posY, 55 + posX, 50 + posY);
        g.drawLine(50 + posX, 45 + posY, 50 + posX, 55 + posY);

        moveTimer.start();
    }

    int segment = 0;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(isParking) return; //execute only when not parking 

        // move along the 1st segment
        if (posY < 100 && segment == 0) {
            setPosY(posY + velX);
        }

        if (posY == 100 && posX == 0 && segment != 1) { //!=1 so it will not be invoked again 
            segment = 1;
            isParking = true; //flag that robot is parking 
            waitTimer.start();
            return;
        }

        // move along the second segment
        if (posX <= 200 && segment == 1) {
            setPosX(posX + velX);
        }

        if (posX == 200 && posY == 100) {
            segment = 2;
        }

        // move along the third segment
        if (posY > 0 && segment == 2) {
            setPosY(posY - velX);
        }

        if (posX == 200 && posY == 0 && segment !=3) {
            segment = 3;
            isParking = true;
            waitTimer.start();
            return;
        }

        // move along the fourth segment
        if (posX < 300 && segment == 3) {
            setPosX(posX + velX);
        }

        if (posX == 300 && posY == 0) {
            segment = 4;
        }

        // move along the fifth segment
        if (posY < 100 && segment == 4) {
            setPosY(posY + velX);
        }

        if (posX == 300 && posY == 100 && segment !=6) {
            segment = 6;
            isParking = true;
            waitTimer.start();
            return;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new Robot0("Robot0", 800, 600));
    }
}
```

TODO:

1. Implement custom painting on JPanel.
2. Simplify  `actionPerformed`
   logic

**Edit:** the following is an implementation with some improvements not necessarily related to question asked:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Robot0 extends JFrame {

    public Robot0(String nom) {
        setTitle(nom);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new Floor());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new Robot0("Robot0"));
    }
}

class Floor extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final int PARKING_TIME = 5000, REPAINT_TIME = 10, W = 400, H = 200;
    private static final int ROOM_SIZE = 30, ROBOT_SIZE = 20, CROSS_SIZE = 10;

    private final Timer moveTimer , waitTimer;
    private boolean isParking = false;

    private int posX = 0, posY = 0;
    private final int velX = 1;

    // pathway
    private static final int PATH_X[] = { 50,  50, 250, 250, 350,  350 };
    private static final int PATH_Y[] = { 50, 150, 150,  50,  50,  150 };
    //rooms
    private static final Point[] ROOM_CENTERS = {new Point(PATH_X[1],PATH_Y[1]),
                                                 new Point(PATH_X[3],PATH_Y[3]),
                                                 new Point(PATH_X[5],PATH_Y[5]) };

    Floor() {
        moveTimer = new Timer(REPAINT_TIME, this);
        waitTimer = new Timer(PARKING_TIME, e-> isParking = false);
        waitTimer.setRepeats(false);
        posX = PATH_X[0]; posY = PATH_Y[0];
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W, H));
        moveTimer.start(); //no need to restart with every paint
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.drawPolyline(PATH_X, PATH_Y, 6);

        // draw rooms
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for(Point center : ROOM_CENTERS){
            drawSquareAround(center, g);
        }

        //robot
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval( posX - ROBOT_SIZE/2 , posY - ROBOT_SIZE/2 , ROBOT_SIZE, ROBOT_SIZE);

        //cross
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(posX - CROSS_SIZE/2, posY, posX + CROSS_SIZE/2, posY);
        g.drawLine(posX, posY - CROSS_SIZE/2, posX,  posY + CROSS_SIZE/2);
    }


    private void drawSquareAround(Point center, Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(center.x - ROOM_SIZE/2, center.y - ROOM_SIZE/2, ROOM_SIZE, ROOM_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(isParking) return; //execute only when not parking

        if (posX <= PATH_X[0]  &&  posY < PATH_Y[1]) {// move along the 1st segment
            setPosY(posY + velX);
        }else if (posX < PATH_X[2] && posY == PATH_Y[1]) { //move along the second segment
            setPosX(posX + velX);
        }else  if (posX == PATH_X[2] && posY > PATH_Y[3]) { //move along the third segment
            setPosY(posY - velX);
        }else if (posY == PATH_Y[3] && posX < PATH_X[4]) {// move along the fourth segment
                setPosX(posX + velX);
        }else if (posX == PATH_X[4] && posY < PATH_Y[5]){// move along the fifth segment
            setPosY(posY + velX);
        }else {
            moveTimer.stop(); //move finished, stop repainting
            return;
        }

        //park if at room center
        if(isRoomCeter()){
            park();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    private void park() {
      isParking = true; //flag that robot is parking
      waitTimer.start();
    }

    private boolean isRoomCeter() {
        for (Point center : ROOM_CENTERS){
            if(posX == center.x && posY == center.y) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public void setPosX(int posX) {
        this.posX = posX;
    }

    public int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    public void setPosY(int posY) {
        this.posY = posY;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but not sure to understand. I had the same code with the JFrame creation in the main() and that worked perfectly, the white circle moved slowly. The freeze happened when I moved the JFrame creation to the constructor. What is the reason?

Comment: **"**_that worked perfectly_**"** I don't think so. The robot was moving and parking but the GUI was nor responsive. You could not move it / resize it or interact with it in any way. You should not sleep on the EDT. Use swing Timer.

Comment: Ok, understood. Many tks

Comment: Tks @c0der. I know this (although I feel very strange not to thank people that help you...). But I commented despite the rules because you said on your profile: "When I take time to answer your questions, I expect you to take time and respond." ;)

Comment: Thank you. That's nice, and [being nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback) is not against the rules (0: